# Trying to associate a dynamics portal user with a dynamics entity record through the portal

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365, adxstudio-portals

So I have a Dynamics 365 solution with a portal. I have created a custom entity to hold records relating to events. What I need to do is provide a way for users to log into the portal and register their interest for these events i.e associate their contact record with the relevant event record.

I have seen that in CRM there is the option to associate the current user to an event when they create one through an insert entity form in the portal, but I can't figure out how to do it from a read-only entity form.

Comment: Are you looking for this one: https://community.adxstudio.com/products/adxstudio-portals/documentation/configuration-guide/entity-list/enhanced-crm-view-filtering/

Comment: Did you try setting up the entity form Metadata to populate the fields?
 https://community.adxstudio.com/products/adxstudio-portals/documentation/configuration-guide/entity-form/entity-form-metadata/

Comment: @ArunVinoth YES! Thank you so much! You have no idea how much I have been looking for something like this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use & configure Entity Form Metadata in entity form, so that the data can be pre-populated including current login portal user as contact in each record.

https://community.adxstudio.com/products/adxstudio-portals/documentation/configuration-guide/entity-form/entity-form-metadata/

Comment: I have tried this several different ways on several different fields and I keep getting SYSTEM in the createdby or ownerid fields.  Any advice? Thanks

Comment: @GrantEagon createdby, modifiedby & ownerid are systemuser lookup fields, they are set from crm user. Portal users are contacts, it cannot be used to fill in systemuser fields..

Comment: @GrantEagon see my another answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49384428/7920473. Upvote if you find useful.