# How to set parent account automatically while creating the contact in CRM portal?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-portals

I have Create and Edit forms in CRM portal. I need users to create or edit the contact record but while creating or editing I want the Account to be setup automatically to the parent account of the logged in user. Is it possible and if yes how can I accomplish this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to associate a dynamics portal user with a dynamics entity record through the portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44757155/trying-to-associate-a-dynamics-portal-user-with-a-dynamics-entity-record-through)

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do that is using a synchronous workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Is possible, you need to add your lookup on the form and populate it with liquid code as is described below!

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        
      $("#new_accountfieldid_name").attr("value", "{{user.fullname}}");
      $("#new_accountfieldid").attr("value", "{{user.id}}");
      $("#new_accountfieldid_entityname").attr("value", "contact");
}
<script>
```